# How to convert the date to ISODate in python as i need to run query on MongoDB using aggregate function in python

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregate, pymongo

```js
[{
    $match: {
        sku: '7908397',
        storeLocationId: 1052,
        $and: [{
                processedDate: {
                    $gte: ISODate('2022-11-05T00:00:00.000Z')
                }
            },
            {
                processedDate: {
                    $lt: ISODate('2022-11-06T00:00:00.000Z')
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

**Including comment text/code below**

above query will throw me error as i can't use ISODate in python....so tried using `date.isoformat()` this doesn't give any output...can anyone help me here.

```js
'$and': [{'processedDate': {'$gte': date.isoformat(day_2)}}, {'processedDate': {'$lt': date.isoformat(yesterday_date)
```

so here i am getting the date's this way:

```py
today_date = datetime.date.today()
yesterday_date = today_date - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
day_2 = today_date - datetime.timedelta(days=2)
```

Comment: above query will throw me error as i can't use ISODate in python....so tried using  date.isoformat() this doesn't give any output...can anyone help me here. 
'$and': [{'processedDate': {'$gte': date.isoformat(day_2)}}, {'processedDate': {'$lt': date.isoformat(yesterday_date)

Comment: so here i am getting the date's this way 
today_date = datetime.date.today()                                                                                            
yesterday_date = today_date - datetime.timedelta(days=1)                                                    
day_2 = today_date - datetime.timedelta(days=2)

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Instead, edit the question with updates. Also, provide sample json documents and expected output.

Comment: `pymongo` will automatically convert Python `datetime` objects to BSON `Date`.  What happens if you try `'processedDate': {'$gte': day_2, '$lt': yesterday_date}`?